# Difference between ./script.sh and sh script.sh

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote script with deafult permission -rw-r--r-- 1. If I run this sh script.sh it get executed, while excuting with ./script it throw permission denied.

What is the difference between both the commands?
Why it's not required change in permission for 'sh script.sh'?

[root@ip safe]# sh test.sh

test

[root@ip safe]# ./test.sh

-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied

Comment: The file isn't a "executable", so it cannot be executed. Running `sh <file>` will execute the command `sh`, it will be found by searching the `$PATH` environment variable, and then executed with two arguments: `sh` and `<file>` in this case the `sh` command will interpret the provided file and run the commands. You can make a file executable with `chmod +x <file>`.

Comment: Note that `sh` **is not bash**. Even when it's the same executable it runs in a limited compatibility mode with started under the `sh` name. If you want full bash capabilities, use `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: Re: execute permissions, it's not specific to sh either. You don't need execute permissions for `python myscript.py`, but _do_ need them for `./myscript.py`; same for every other language (including compiled executables, for which the interpreter is `ld.so`).

Comment: Going back to bash-vs-sh: `sh` is the generic name for whichever POSIX sh interpreter your operating system provides; it _only_ promises features in the POSIX specification will be available (and many major operating systems, including Debian and Ubuntu, use a smaller/faster-to-startup sh interpreter like `ash` or `dash` instead of bash). `bash` is a specific interpreter with a lot of extensions. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell

Comment: Also, note that giving scripts a `.sh` extension is frowned on, _especially_ if they're actually bash scripts and not sh scripts. http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful is an essay on the subject that the #bash IRC channel has pointed people to for years. (To pithily oversummarize: "Command names don't have extensions; you run "ls", not "ls.elf", and executable scripts are commands").

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between both the commands?

`sh script.sh` tells the `sh` program to run the script.

`./script.sh` says to run the script using the program that the script defines with a hashbang at the start (or in the default shell if not hashbang).

Note that you may well end up with completely different results, depending on whether the script has a hashbang, for a couple of reasons:

- Even when `sh` is `bash`, when it's invoked as `sh` it runs in a limited compatibility mode (thank you [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for [pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539327/difference-between-script-sh-and-sh-script-sh/71539366#comment126439692_71539327) in the comments on the question).
- The script might run with something completely different from a shell. It might start with `#!/bin/node` and contain JavaScript code to run in Node.js. In that case, `./script.sh` will work but `sh script.sh` will fail, because `sh` will treat the script as a shell script.

> Why it's not required change in permission for 'sh script.sh'?

Because in that case, what you're executing is the `sh` program, which is marked executable (it's `sh` that then reads and performs the commands in the script, but the script doesn't have to be executable for that). When you do `./script.sh`, you're treating it as executable, so it needs to have the executable permissions bit set.