# Why can I run "bash myscript" without +x permissions on myscript?

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I am learning about UNIX commands on my Mac. I have configured Bash (I know zsh is better, but I did Bash to follow a tutorial, so please don't suggest switching to zsh). I have written a script in `/Users/dw/bin/hello.txt`. I thought that I would need to alter permissions before I could execute the script, but I was actually able to run `bash hello.txt` and get the expected output without changing permissions for that file. The permissions for the file are `rw-r--r--`. Any idea why I am able to execute the script in `hello.txt` without doing `chmod` and adding `a+x` etc.?

Comment: See ["Difference between ./script.sh and sh script.sh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539327/difference-between-script-sh-and-sh-script-sh) and the many linked duplicates.

Comment: See [What is the advantage of doing `chmod` on a `.sh` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71913244/4154375).

Answer (score 5):

You are not executing the file. You are executing `bash` and passing the file. Bash will then read the file and run it line by line.

To execute the file itself, you must enter `./hello.txt` (this will fail if the file doesn't have the `x` bit set).

Executing it this way will also respect the shebang line (if specified). Running `bash hello.txt` will always run it with bash, even if the shebang specified a different interpreter (e.g. `sh` or `python`).